# Run of dialyzer after annotation with typer did not show any warnings

Tags: erlang, typechecking, dialyzer

In a project with about 6000 lines of Erlang code but no type `-spec()` annotation yet I tried the following:

```
typer --annotate *.erl
```

The I replaced all `*.erl` files with the annotated ones and ran

```
dialyzer --src -c *.erl
```

I expected to get lots of warnings (ran the dialyzer/typer combination the first time) but after doing its thing all dialyzer reported were 2 old calls in user_default to meanwhile nonexistent functions.

No other of the default warnings did trigger.

Did I make a mistake using it or is a result like this common?

Is the combination of auto annotation with `typer` and `dialyzer` not so useful or am I just lucky and my code doesn't have issues?

---

Sidenote: I had to comment out 3 or 4 `-spec()`s because `dialyzer` [crashed on them](http://erlang.2086793.n4.nabble.com/Dialyzer-v2-2-0-crash-tp3487625p3487625.html).

I'm using Dialyzer v2.2.0 and TypEr version v0.1.7.4 from Erlang R13B04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a side effect of reporting a bug on the erlang-bugs list I got an detailed answer this from Kostis Sagonas, the inventor of dialyzer and typer.

To my side question I got the following great and detailed answer:

> [On Sun, May 1, 2011 at 5:53 PM, Kostis Sagonas wrote:](http://erlang.2086793.n4.nabble.com/Dialyzer-v2-2-0-crash-tp3487625p3487625.html)
>
> > Peer Stritzinger wrote:
> >
> > BTW: is it normal not to get any warnings when just doing --annotate
> >     in typer and then dialyzer with no manually tweaked spec's
>
> Yes. In fact, typer is just a front end for dialyzer's basic type inference (i.e. without the warning identification component).
>
> IMO, there is very little point in doing this if you do not intend to manually "massage" the specs that you get and provide more info for some of them.  Take a look at your previous program.  The fact that the two <<*:64,*:_*8>> types were referring to the same quantity could be expressed better if you introduced a type as in:
>
> ```
>   -type packet() :: <<_:64,_:_*8>>,
> ```
>
> Similarly for channel:
>
> ```
>   -type channel() :: atom() | pid() |{atom(),_}.
> ```
>
> and then the spec would already look better.  Also, dialyzer/typer has no info on what type of fun you intend to use in the second argument of function `recv/3` but you do!  From the code it is clear that it takes `#can_pkt{}` record, so why don't you add appropriate types to its fields and introduce a type for it?
>
> ```
>   -record(can_pkt, {id :: id(), data :: binary(), timestamp :: ts()}).
>   -type can_pkt() :: #can_pkt{}.
> ```
>
> then the specs can look much better:
>
> ```
>   -spec recv(packet(), fun((can_pkt()) -> R), channel()) -> R.
>   -spec decode(packet()) -> can_pkt().
> ```
>
> and note that I've used a placeholder type variable `R` to denote the fact that function `recv/2` returns whatever type the fun in its second argument returns. You probably know what this type is so you should also introduce a type for it and use its proper name.
>
> Hope this helps,
>
> Kostis
>
> PS. It's a pity you posted this in erlang-bugs as the information contained in the above is IMO more interesting than the actual bug.

Since he refers to a code fragment, I included in my bug report, I include it here.  The following code fragment was automatically annotated by `typer --annotate`:

```
-record(can_pkt, {id, data, timestamp}).

-spec recv(<<_:64,_:_*8>>,fun((_) -> 
      any()),atom() | pid() | {atom(),_}) -> any().

recv(Packet, Recv_fun, Chan) ->
    P = decode(Packet),
    #can_pkt{id=Can_id, data=Can_data}=P,
    Recv_fun(P).

-spec decode(<<_:64,_:_*8>>) -> 
      #can_pkt{id::<<_:11>>,data::binary(),timestamp::char()}.

decode(<<_:12, Len:4, Timestamp:16,
        0:3, Id:11/bitstring, 0:18,
        Data:Len/binary, _/binary>>) ->
    #can_pkt{id=Id, data=Data, timestamp=Timestamp}.
```